# ImportError: DLL load failed - during numpy import

Tags: python, numpy, dll

I have the software with its own Python2 and Python3 editors. I was working with it for a very long time without any problems. that there is DLL loading error when I try importing numpy, here is the full error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Program Files\Software\Software 2018\Python36_x64\lib\site-
packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>   
 from . import multiarray
```

ImportError: DLL load failed: The file cannot be accessed by the system.

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last): 
 File "<string>", line 1 (56), in <module> 
 File "C:\Program Files\Software\Software 2018\Python36_x64\lib\site-
packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
 from . import add_newdocs  
File "C:\Program Files\Software\Software 2018\Python36_x64\lib\site-
packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>    
from numpy.lib import add_newdoc 
 File "C:\Program Files\Software\Software 2018\Python36_x64\lib\site-
packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
  from .type_check import *
 File "C:\Program Files\Software\Software 2018\Python36_x64\lib\site-
packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 11, in <module>   
import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
 File "C:\Program Files\Software\Software 2018\Python36_x64\lib\site-
packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>  
 raise ImportError(msg)

ImportError: 
Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.

Original error was: DLL load failed: The file cannot be accessed by the system.
```

I have anaconda on my machine by the way and I have reinstalled the software 2x times, deleted and reinstalled numpy itself and nothing ...the same problem still there.

```
NOTE: Python2 within the software doesn't have this issue

NOTE: the Software and Software 2018 are the actual names of the software but 
a way to hide it because of the confidentiality
```

Comment: What numpy version are you using?

Comment: The software does have a requirement to use only 1.14.2 version of numpy. I was trying installing different versions, the results was the same though.

Comment: Numpy 1.14.2 supports python versions  2.7 and 3.4 - 3.6. More about that [here](https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.14.2-notes.html). What is your python3 version?

Comment: The version is: 3.6

Comment: Perhaps the ```PATH``` adjustments are failing at import. Does the ```site-packages\numpy\.libs``` directory exist and does it contain ```*.dll``` files?

Comment: `site-packages\numpy\.libs` does contain only one `.dll` file. Can you please elaborate on  `PATH` comment, is there any `health-check` guide on that?

Comment: Does [this](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/12957) issue's answer solve your problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216930/discussion-between-dwij-mehta-and-kamran-abbasov).